# Apps are unable to access internet in Android Device with Proxy

Tags: android, proxy, jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

I have a requirement of doing Performance Testing of Android apps as given here [[http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy]](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy%5d) . But when I change the proxy hostname of my Android device to that of my laptop's IP, the apps are unable to access the internet. Though, the browser works fine and are able to send the requests. It is getting recorded in JMeter as well. But, the apps are unable to access the internet. Is it because they don't have the permission to access the internet because of the changed proxy?

Answer (score 0):

A main reason that the apps won't work but the browser will, is the use of https.
If you are using the secure protocol in your applications, they don't know how to retrieve the certificate through the proxy, but the browser does. You will have to get the certificate yourself, and put it on the phone.

As is written in the article you mentioned:

> Note that Android supports only HTTP proxy. If your application uses
>   an HTTPS connection, then you may use an additional application that
>   performs with HTTPS proxing.